# Ошибка при добавлении иконки в action bar

Tags: android, activity

Как добавить иконку приложения в бар есле поначалу нету? Вставил код:

```
ActionBarActivity.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

Подчеркивается красным `setIcon` и пишет "Cannot resolve method `setIcon(int)`"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В чем именно возникла проблема?

Comment: добавил код....

Answer (score 1):

```
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```